# Replacing jaxb:globalBindings with schema level bindings

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a global binding that I would like to modify the scope of (schema level), but the syntax that I am using is not working. Preferably I would like to put it inline, but externally at the schema level is fine. Here is my global binding:

```
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true">
    <xjc:serializable uid="7490292371592404588" />
    <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
        printMethod="com.acme.schema.adapter.MyDateTimeAdapter.marshallDate"
        parseMethod="com.acme.schema.adapter.MyDateTimeAdapter.unmarshallDate" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
```

Here is what I have tried unsuccessfully:

```
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="myschema.xsd" generateIsSetMethod="true">
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
        printMethod="com.acme.schema.adapter.MyDateTimeAdapter.marshallDate"
        parseMethod="com.acme.schema.adapter.MyDateTimeAdapter.unmarshallDate" />
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I have not been able to find a good example of how this is done.

Comment: May be do want to show the how the generated class looks, and what is expected?

Comment: The generated class has members of type Date rather than the type XmlGregorianCalendar for those that are xs:date

Comment: how is the xsd defined for the element?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 targetNamespace="X"
 xmlns="X">
 
 <xs:complexType name="S">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="theDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"
    maxOccurs="1" />
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

Comment: Here is a solution, but I am not wild about it as I have to add a binding for every field.<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="myschema.xsd">
  <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='theDate']">
   <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date"
    printMethod="com.acme.schema.adapter.MyDateTimeAdapter.marshallDate"
    parseMethod="com.acme.schema.adapter.MyDateTimeAdapter.unmarshallDate" />
  </jaxb:bindings>
 </jaxb:bindings>

Comment: I think I got your point.